# Server Error in '/' Application MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, search

I have created a search function on my website that uses a partial view for users to input their search criteria, the results of the search should be displayed on the results page. My issues is that when the search is run the results page doesn't display instead I get a `Server Error in '/' Application.` error.

Any help would be great full

_SearchView

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
{ 
<div class="search-button1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="SearchString" id="SearchString">

  </div>
}
```

Search Controller

```
namespace BiteWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class SearchController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Search/
        public ActionResult _SearchView()
        {

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Results(string SearchString)
        {
            using (var objCtx = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var Restaurant = from u in objCtx.Restaurants
                           select u;


                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
                {
                    Restaurant = Restaurant.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(SearchString));
                }

                return View(Restaurant);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results page

```
@model IEnumerable<BiteWebsite.Models.Restaurant>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cuisine)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StreetNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StreetName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.County)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contactnumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Website)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserID)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuisine)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StreetNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StreetName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contactnumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Website)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: please run you application in debug mode and see which line throws an exception in your post action.
just noticed. your action is marked as `[HttpPost]` but you set form method as `FormMethod.Get`. change that to `FormMethod.Post`

Comment: Thanks I changed the from method to Post and discovered that my SQL server services were not running.